# React Functional Component props does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a functional component to display these divs.
I have also another component that uses the displayCounter component and keeps track of a state.
My state is a counter and I have some buttons to increase and decrease the counter.

Let's say that the state is

state = {
counter: 0
}

The div with the Example 1 does not display the changes of the counter.
But the div with Example 2 works fine?

So when I click to increase button div 1 always displays 0, but div 2 works fine.

Can somebody explain to me the reason?

```
import React from 'react';

const displayCounter = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div> Example 1: {props.value} </div>
            <div> Example 2: <span>{props.value}</span> </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default displayCounter;
```

Add a comment if you want to post the full code for the mini-app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CounterControl from '../../components/CounterControl/CounterControl';
import DisplayCounter from '../../components/DisplayCounter';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        counter: 0
    }

    counterChangedHandler = () => {
        this.setState( ( prevState ) => { return { counter: prevState.counter + 1 } } )
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <DisplayCounter value={this.state.counter}/>
                <CounterControl label="Increment" clicked={() => this.counterChangedHandler( 'inc' )} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: How do you update the state?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  It would be super helpful if you made an online, sandbox demo of this.

Comment: @Tomas    counterChangedHandler = () => {
        this.setState( ( prevState ) => { return { counter: prevState.counter + 1 } } )
    }

Comment: I see no logical reason why "Example 1" and "Example 2" would be showing different things when they are both `{props.value}`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/: https://f6vnw.csb.app/

Comment: Example 1 and example 2 both seem to work perfectly in your demo, no?  This problem appears to be not a problem?  ***"So when I click to increase button div 1 always displays 0, but div 2 works fine."***

Comment: @HoldOffHunger hmm in firefox yes. But in chrome no !

Comment: What's your Chrome version?  Works fine in my Chrome.  And is it necessary to yell?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about it!  I have chrome v 86.0.4240.193.  And it works wonderfully.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  My version is 86.0.4240.183 (on linux)

Comment: Are you testing Chrome both with your own environment and with the codesandbox.io link?  Sometimes ReactJS version can matter, too.  I would upgrade both to the most recent.  I have had trouble with chrome/chromium on Linux, too, in general.  Not sure what to say, works great here.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Okay thank you! It;s wotk on my firefox and chromium. But not in my chrome. Both local and in codesandbox.io it is the same.

Comment: Huh!  Maybe it's just a fluke?  Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger thank you any way!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use props, props is a old way, you should use this

```
import React from 'react';

const displayCounter = ({ counter }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div> Example 1: {counter} </div>
            <div> Example 2: <span>{counter}</span> </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default displayCounter;
```

Comment: You are using props, you are just using them with destructuring.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You know, it doesn't seem like the OP's code is broken.  They posted a sandbox demo of it.  It works for me, does it work for you?  https://f6vnw.csb.app/

Comment: @JacobSmit what do you mean?

Comment: @ManolisP. Just stating that Mace is still using props they are just destructured. Look at object destructuring: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @JacobSmit so it take the props and only keeps the counter prop if i understand correctly?

Comment: They are all still passed to the function but only accessible if included in the destructuring. You can use it when you want to break up an object into easier to access variables, or when you want to only use part of an object. Say you had props of `{ propA: 1, propB: 2, propC: 3 }` using destructuring you could have `{ propA, propB: prop2, ...rest }` this would give you access to `propA`, `propB` accessible as `prop2` and all the remaining properties in `rest`.

Comment: @JacobSmit I understand! The problem was the chrome. But it's nice to learn thinks that you don't know yet! Thank you!